# Cámara dinámica con Unity2D

Tags: c#, motor-de-juego, unity3d, 2d

Quiero hacer una cámara como la de los juegos [Hotline Miami](http://store.steampowered.com/app/219150/) o [Nuclear Throne](http://store.steampowered.com/app/242680/); una cámara dinámica que sigue al jugador dejándolo en la zona central de la pantalla.

Este es un [tutorial que explica cómo hacerlo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTup4IwsODA). Tengo un código que puede servir, pero la cámara presenta problemas de posición y si muevo al jugador, la cámara se corre más de la cuenta.

Aquí está el código:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class shauldspading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public Transform Mouse;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        //var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        //Vector3 Mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        float xTo, yTo;
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        xTo = Player.position.x + lengthdir_x(Mathf.Min(9,Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, Mouse.transform.position)), Mouse.position);
        yTo = Player.position.y + lengthdir_y(Mathf.Min (9, Vector3.Distance (Player.transform.position, Mouse.transform.position)), Mouse.position);
        pos.x += (xTo - pos.x) / 25;
        pos.y += (yTo - pos.y) / 25;
        transform.position = pos;
    }

    float lengthdir_x(float len, Vector3 dir)
    {
        dir = dir.normalized * len;
        return dir.x;
    }

    float lengthdir_y(float len, Vector3 dir)
    {
        dir = dir.normalized * len;
        return dir.y;
    }
}
```

Ya probé el código y me funciona, pero tiene el inconveniente de que no es fijo y si me muevo presenta problemas de posición.

¿Qué debería hacer para solucionar ese problema y mejorar el código que está arriba?

**Actualizacion:** Video camara dinamica [Nuclear Throne ejemplo de camara dinamica 2D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FhB1w_7Qp0) .

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Ness, por favor explica cual es el problema que estas encontrando, no se entiende bien el comportamiento esperado y el que estas obteniendo.

Comment: Hola  como dice @Dzyann por lo que muestras es un poco dificil imaginarse el comportamiento que estas obteniendo, intenta crear un mcve o hacer un video del comportamiento que estas obteniendo y una explicacion de como quieres que funcione, por otro lado, las lineas que mas me llama la tension son ->pos.x += (xTo - pos.x) / 25; y la siguiente que hace referencia a pos.y, ese -> / 25, quizas te este generando un comportamiento extraño pero no puede confirmarlo de ninguna manera pero te lo digo por que igual esta por ahi,

Comment: si no es asi pues nada, pero si obtines la posicion neutra pero despues le hace /25 siendo la posicion neutra no se si eso te llevara a un comportamiento extraño Saludos

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que quizas no sepas lo que es un mcve he buscado el link en el site pero no lo encontre, te dejo esto para que te hagas una idea pero esta en ingles espero ayude http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scritp autoria de [kaito](http://unityspain.com/topic/34821-camara-dinamica-unity2d/)

funciona genial.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

//El script se añade a la camara
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]

public class script3 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target; //Gameobject que hace de pivot
    public float smoothTime = 0.5f; //tiempo smooth
    public Vector2 desplazamiento = new Vector2(3f, 2f); //desplazamiento de origen
    public Vector2 resolucion = new Vector2(800f,600f); //resolucion de origen


    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero; //velocidad smooth
    Vector3 centerScreen; //centro pantalla
    Vector3 aspect; //aspecto ratio


    void Start() {


        if(this.target == null){

            Destroy(this);
            Debug.Log("Asignar Target en script3 - " + this.name);
            Debug.Break();
            return;

        }

        this.centerScreen = new Vector3(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f, 0f);
        //Recalcular desplazamiento en relacion a pantalla actual
        this.desplazamiento = new Vector2(this.desplazamiento.x * Screen.width / this.resolucion.x,
                                          this.desplazamiento.y * Screen.height / this.resolucion.y);
        this.aspect = new Vector3(this.desplazamiento.x / Screen.width, this.desplazamiento.y / Screen.height, 0f);

    }

    void Update () {

        Vector3 temp = this.target.position + Vector3.Scale(Input.mousePosition - this.centerScreen, this.aspect);
        this.transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(this.transform.position, temp, ref this.velocity, this.smoothTime);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hace tiempo había realizado algo similar, de hecho es relativamente sencillo.

Te dejo el enlace al codigo que utilicé para uno de mis juegos:

https://github.com/moscoquera/Cubos/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Camara_seguirObjeto.cs

Este script debe ser añadido a la cámara en cuestión, y en "objetivo" se debe referenciar al jugador en el mapa.

Comment: El código esta genial, pero el movimiento  de la cámara tiene que ser con respecto a la posición de mouse y objeto a seguir , me explico si el mouse se mueve  hacia abajo de la pantalla la cámara, la cámara se mueve hacia abajo pero con respecto al objeto a seguir pero sin perderle de vista  , pero si el objeto a seguir se mueve la cámara  simplemente los sigue  el como en este vídeo:                           [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FhB1w_7Qp0&feature=youtu.be]

Comment: @NessMastert_Ration usted debe actualizar su pregunta con este link de vídeo.

Answer (score 0):

He visto el vídeo de "Nuclear Throne" que tú añadiste en la sección de comentarios. Mi respuesta sobre ese comportamiento.

Primero, defina cuan lejos la cámara se puede mover con respecto a la posición del jugador, por ejemplos en *pixels*. Por ejemplo si la pantalla es 800x600, y tú dejas que la cámara se pueda mover a una distancia de la mitad de la pantalla, entonces los límites son +/- 300 verticalmente y +/- 400 horizontalmente.

Segundo, en cualquier momento tú puedes saber/consultar a cuantos *pixels* el mouse está del centro de la pantalla. Convierta el resultado a [-1...+1] usando los límites que usted definió anteriormente. Por ejemplo si el mouse está en `( 253 ; 402 )`, este será transformado a `( -0,37 ; 0,34 )`. Si cualquier número está más que `+1,0` o menos que `-1,0`, haz "clamp" a `+1,0` o `-1,0`.

Finalmente, multiplicar las `coordinates` transformadas por los límites del movimiento, y añada esto con la posición del jugador en el mundo. Por ejemplo si el jugador está en `( 8042 ; -5732 )`, el centro de la cámara se debe poner en:

```
( 8042 ; -5732 ) + ( -0,37 * 400 ; 0,34 * 300 ) = ( 7894 ; -5630 )
```

o conceptualmente:

```
( pos. del jugador ) + ( mitad del res. de pant. ) * ( pos. del mouse en la pant. ) 
    = ( pos. de cam. final )
```

Espero que esto le ayude.